# Orthogonal function to find for transient diffusion equation in spherical coordinates

Tags: inner-products, bessel-functions, eigenfunctions

I have a question on eigenvalue and eigenfunction in spherical coordinates.

Let $0 \leq u \leq 1$, and a function $j_0(u)$ (zero order spherical Bessel first kind):

$$ j_0(u) = \frac{\sin(u)}{u} $$

Let us define the roots $v_n > 0$ of $j_1(u) = - \partial_u j_0(u)$ as:

$$ j_1(v_n) = \frac{\sin(v_n) - v_n \cos(v_n)}{v_n^2} = 0 $$

Then we have the roots defined by:

$$ v_n = \tan(v_n) $$

**The question:**

I am looking for a function $f(u v_n)$ which obeys to:

$$ \langle j_0(u v_n) \vert f(u v_m) \rangle = \int_0^1 u^2 j_0(u v_n) f(u v_m) d u \propto \delta_{n,m} $$

Do you have an idea ? I tried $f(u v_n) = j_0(u v_n)$ but it does not work, I started to try $f(u v_n) = j_1(u v_n)$ but that leads to complicated functions... maybe there is a simple rule? I know the orthogonality relation for:

$$ \langle j_0(u \lambda_n) \vert j_0(u \lambda_m)  \rangle \propto \delta_{n,m} $$

with $j_0(\lambda_n) = 0$, but that's it...

Comment: Are you sure $j_0(u v_n)$ doesn't work? Remember that the $v_n$ must satisfy $\tan v_n = v_n$, and thus $\sin v_n = v_n\cos v_n$.

Comment: Thank you, amazing, I redo my computations and it is zero everywhere. So it is $\delta_{n,m} (2 v_n - sin(2 v_n))/(4 v_n)$.
Do we have a reference for general orthogonality even for the most weird boundary conditions and weird eigenvalue in partial differential equation (mainly Poisson and Helmholtz) ? The orthogonality is often satisfied by magic I mean

Comment: Look into [Sturm-Liouville theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory). There are some theorems about what kind of differential operators must have eigenfunctions with different eigenvalues be orthogonal. The Poisson and Helmholtz operators fall into this category.

Comment: Thanks boss, understood. Infact at the point the BC are of Robin type, since the Sturm Liouville operator is self adjoint, then the eigenfunctions are orthogonal... thanks internet, f#ck university